# Storing Hash in Sqlite table . Do I use Serialization?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm creating an app that has to store historical financial data for various stocks.
I currently have a stock table where the columns are stock symbol, stockname along with numerical data which I'm trying to decide how to store.

For example, for the column stockprice, I want to store an entire hash where the key is the date as a string and the value is the stock price. This information should be easily accessible(fast random access). I've read a bit about serializing, but I wonder if this is the best option(or if it's even applicable at all). Is there a way to instead automatically generate an sqlite table for each stock entered and create columns representing the date and rows representing the stockprice?

I appreciate all insight into this matter and perhaps some clarification on whether this is exactly where I should use serialization or whether there is a better alternative

EDIT 1: Is ActiveModel Serialization relevant? (http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

EDIT 2: Is it advisable to consider instead creating a Stockprice model & table where the model belongs_to a stock and a stock has_many stockprices. THe stockprice table would have a regular id, a stock_id(for which it belongs) to and a date column and a stockprice value column. I'd appreciate some analysis on the run-time memory-time usage of this in comparison to serialization and how to analyze it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is possible to store it as a hash. I don't have any metrics for `serialize` but I would suggest starting this way and optimizing your data storage later if you begin to notice a significant impact on your application.

You're migration would look something like this (be sure to use the text data type):

```
def self.up
    add_column :stocks, :price, :text
end
```

In your model you will need to add

```
serialize :price
```

You will be able to create price as a hash and store it directly.

```
stock = Stock.new
stock.price = { :date => "#{Time.now}", :amount => 25.2 }
stock.save
```

EDIT: I would start with the serialization unless you have designed functionality that is specific to stock_price. Since the convention in Rails is to have a model per each table, you would end up with a class for stock_price. It isn't necessary to dedicate a class for stock_price unless you have specific methods in mind for that class. Also, depending on your design, you may be able to keep the stocks class more cohesive by keeping the stock price as an attribute of stocks.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned 'This information should be easily accessible(fast random access)' - in which case serialized column is not a good option. Lets say you keep 20 years of data, then it would be 20*365 key value pairs in the serialized price. But you might be interested in only a subset of this for an usecase - say plotting last 6 months. If you go with the serialize option, that entire data (for price field) will be transported from db to ruby process and gets de-serialized.Then again you need to filter the price hash in ruby process. Where as in case of a seperate table for price, db can do the filtering for you and you can have a fast response with good indices.

Have you explored any time series dbs?